# Django formtools and instance variable for form instance

Tags: django, django-formwizard

I'm using Django formtools for creating multistep forms. The problem is that I have no idea how to pass unique ID to the form instance. Like this:

1. User goes to form step 1 - ie. starts the wizard from the beginning. Unique random ID is created.
2. ID can be accessed in all steps and it will remain constant until done().
3. If the user steps back to step 1, the ID will still remain constant.
4. If the user starts the form from the beginning (clearing all previous data), a new ID will be created.

But how can this be done? There is no **init** to utilize. initial_dict, on the other hand will remain constant in ALL form instances and point 4 is not fulfilled.

Any ideas how to tackle this?

Comment: have you looked at `get_context_data` function? You can use it to check for the step and if some requirement is met you can create a new ID. You can use it in combination of `get_form_initial` function to create an ID when the wizard is initialised.

Comment: Yeah, I've used both of them. The problem is that I have no idea where to actually set the new ID? I have not found any function that gets called before proceeding to step 1 and where I could store instance variables.
get_form_initial() gets called at every step.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this:

```
class MyWizardView(SessionWizardView):
    unique_id == ""

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        This method handles GET requests.

        If a GET request reaches this point, the wizard assumes that the user
        just starts at the first step or wants to restart the process.
        The data of the wizard will be resetted before rendering the first step
        """
        self.storage.reset()

        # reset the current step to the first step.
        self.storage.current_step = self.steps.first
        unique_id = # Insert ID generator here #
        return self.render(self.get_form())
```